# Fantasy series with a warrior elf who had magic tattoos

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a series of fantasy novels around early 2000. I think the name was *the Cartographers Map*, the other title was *Hunters Moon* (*Something Moon?*) but I've searched of these titles and not found any suitable results.

I remember there was a warrior elf with magic tattoos that glowed blue. I also remember the main villain was an ice queen from the north lands named Chytrine(?).

There were dinosaur-like birds on the evil army's side. There were many different states / countries around a vast lake. There were many different armies and magical groups. It was a very violent series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [*DragonCrown War Cycle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DragonCrown_War_Cycle) series of books.

> *The DragonCrown War Cycle is a four book fantasy series consisting of a prequel, The Dark Glory War, and three main volumes, Fortress Draconis, When Dragons Rage, and The Grand Crusade. The books were written by Michael A. Stackpole and published by Bantam Spectra, a subsidiary of Randomhouse inc. over the course of 4 years from 2000-2003. The books follow a group of heroes as they struggle to bring to fruition the Norrington Prophecy, so that they can defeat **the evil Queen of the north, Chytrine,** and save the southern kingdoms from destruction.*

[image]

Comment: Yes. Dragoncrown War Cycle by Michael A Stackpole! That is definetly the one thank you everyone. It is a goid read and i look forward to re reading.